# Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, foreach

store a query in array and call the result in view page show Property [id] does not exist on this collection

in controller

```
foreach($carvalue as $row){
               $products[]=DB::table('products')->where('id',$row['product_id'] )->get();
           }
```

and pass the products variable to view page and print the value like

```
 foreach($products as $prod){ 
        if($prod->id==$rows['product_id']){
        //code
        }
    }
```

show the error and i dd($produts) the result is

```
    array:2 [▼
  0 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#491 ▼
    #items: array:1 [▼
      0 => {#503 ▼
        +"id": "130"
        +"title": "Rfdfd"
        +"sku": "vbff"
        +"sub_title": "RC10 Matte Graphite"

      }
    ]
  }
  1 => Illuminate\Support\Collection {#505 ▶}
]
```

why show this type error and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

In your query, replace `get()` with `first()`

```
$products[]=DB::table('products')->where('id',$row['product_id'] )->first();
```

#### OR

reference the first (and only) `$products` as `$products[0]`, so it gets the `id` from the FIRST (and only, in your case) product

```
 foreach($products[0] as $prod){ 
        if($prod->id==$rows['product_id']){
        //code
        }
    }
```